# Java web applcation - accessing war files from code

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC to develop simple REST interface for one service.

As one of the methods return an xml representation of object I decided to use `JAXB` to map my classes to xml files.

I annotated my classes but I found out that in order to do any validation I need to deliver schema to my marshaller object.

Because we are using `maven` for bulding I added `JAXB` plugin to my `pom.xml`. I can see that the schema files are being generated during build phase but now I have a problem with reading those at runtime.

Because I am planning to have only one controller in my application I wanted to load schema file when the controller is being created by Spring Framework.

I tried using `context.getResourceAsStream("schema.xsd");` but with no luck, I am getting `null` return value.

My schema files are being deployed to

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Open311/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
```

does Spring framework provide any alternative way of reading some static files at startup so I can access them in some way from my code?

Also I want to note that I amdeploying to `Tomcat` from eclipse-level server view, maybe this is also important.

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

[Spring 3.0 inject files as resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484594/spring-3-0-inject-files-as-resources)

and also this one:

[Inject a file resource into Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280115/inject-a-file-resource-into-spring-bean?rq=1)

which describes how to inject a `Resource`.

If that doesn't work, open the Navigator view of Eclpse and make sure the XSD files are actually in the classes directory. If not, you may need to do a `clean` build.