# Spring Controller Injected Properties Turn Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ioc

I have a situation very similar to "[Inject a file resource into Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280115/inject-a-file-resource-into-spring-bean)"

I have a controller that uses some .jasper compiled files and I am declaring them as such

```
//...
@Controller
public class InvoicingController {

private Resource quoteTemplate;
...//
```

And in my context configuration file

```
<bean id="invoicingController" class="x.x.InvoicingController">
    <property name="quoteTemplate" value="/WEB-INF/jasper/Quote.jasper" />
...
```

I set a breakpoint on the `setQuoteTemplate()` function and it is being called and the `Resource` object is being set properly when I initialize the container.   However when I actually hit the controller `quoteTemplate` is null.

I am under the understanding that Controllers are singletons and unless there is a gap in my understanding I am not sure why the values that are set during the container's initialization become null when I hit a url that the controller handles.

EDIT:

Thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis

I ended up declaring beans as such:

```
    <bean id="quoteFile" class="java.io.File">
        <constructor-arg value="resources/jasper/Quote.jasper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="quoteTemplate" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
        <constructor-arg ref="quoteFile" />
    </bean>
```

And then `@Autowire`ing the dependencies as such

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("quoteTemplate") private Resource quoteTemplate;
```

`@Qualifier` is used because I have multiple `Resource` implementation classes declared as beans and this makes sure the correct one gets used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't be using both the `@Controller` annotation and a `<bean>` declaration, unless you don't have a `component-scan`. You will end up with two bean definitions where the last one will overwrite the first one.

In this case, it seems like the component-scanned bean definition comes second and overwrites the bean you created with `<bean>`.

Choose which bean declaration method you want to use.

Comment: Is it possible to declare `Resource` beans that I can then @Autowire in my annotated controller?

Comment: @benashby Of course it is. Pick your choice of `Resource` implementation, declare a `bean` for it with the properties you want. Then `@Autowired` it. You might want to use `@Qualified` to use its id.

Comment: Yes, you can use `@Autowired` for beans declared in XML.