# Spring Injection of XML Data Files to Java Classes

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss

Is there a way to easily use Spring Injection to grab one or more *.xml data files from a folder location (either in a deployed *.war or on a server folder) and inject that data from the *.xml files into a Java class (e.g. in a web service)?  I have been asked by another programmer if I can do this.

I've had a look at a few links on stackoverflow, but so far the easiest way I've found is to put the *.xml files into a particular folder location (e.g. WEB-INF/classes) and use something like this to retrieve them:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/data.xml")
```

The above method is easy; however, it is obviously not Spring Injection.  Is there a way to do this using Spring Injection instead?  I would have thought that since configuration files can be loaded this way, that xml data could also be loaded similarly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides a class called [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) which you can use to inject resource files into a spring bean. So you can do this:

```
public class Consumer {

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        DataInputStream resourceStream = new DataInputStream(resource.getInputStream());
        // ... use the stream as usual
    }

    ...
}
```

Then:

```
<bean class="Consumer">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:path/to/file.xml"/>
</bean>
```

or,

```
<bean class="Consumer">
    <property name="resource" value="file:path/to/file.xml"/>
</bean>
```

You can also directly use the `@Value` annotation:

```
public class Consumer {

    @Value("classpath:path/to/file.xml")
    private Resource resource;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Still having trouble with the above setup you recommend: The Resource (the xml file) is never found, regardless of whether I use classpath or file in either a <bean> entry or a @Value entry.  Will keep trying.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis Make sure you are not using a `/` at the beginning of the class path. It should be `classpath:WEB-INF/classes/data.xml` and not `classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/data.xml`.

Comment: ok.  Do I add the <bean> entry into beans.xml, or into applicationContext.xml?

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis I would think applicationContext.xml. The file beans.xml is used for CDI not Spring.

Comment: Thanks.  I also had a look at the related link, which uses @Controller : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280115/inject-a-file-resource-into-spring-bean

Comment: I got this working eventually, with a bit more detail.  A complete code example is here:  http://www.simplespringtutorial.com/resourceinjection.html  .  Thanks for the help.